# 0x only outputting small Graphs

Tags: node.js, debugging, trace, perf

I am using [0x](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x#readme) to create Flame Graphs. Only it is outputting the first 500 millsec or so. I have run it on **different code bases** but all the output is capped at about 11 mb `v8.log.json` and 250kb for `v8.log`

Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> The X-Axis is not time, it's alphabetically sorted according to function name.

[0x/docs/ui.md](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/0x/blob/master/docs/ui.md#ui)

Just run your loop over you code and the more you exercise it, the larger it will appear on the graph